# Log Into FT.com with Python's requests

Tags: python, http, scripting, python-requests

I'm trying to write a script which will log into my FT.com account and pull down some data for me.

The first hurdle is obviously logging in. I'm using Pythons Requests library for this.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests


# log into FT website
log_in_url = 'https://accounts.ft.com/login'
my_email = 'my@emaill.com'
my_pass = 'mypassword'
data = {'email': my_email,
        'password': my_pass,
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    log_in_request = session.post(log_in_url, data=data)
    # prints log-in page with error about contacting cus. service
    print log_in_request.content
```

It just redirects me back to the login page. It doesn't say 'incorrect details' or anything (they're definitely correct). It just won't let me log in. I suspect something is wrong with my POST request - like I'm missing headers or cookies or something.

Anybody know what might be going on?

Cheers,

Dean

Comment: I suggest you to open your browser web developer tools, check which headers/data are sent during login, figure out where required comes from, then try to reproduce it with requests

Comment: Try doing a get to the page first with the Session object.

Comment: Tried both of these and a million other things. Nothing seems to work for this site.

Comment: You also added a user-agent and added the Sign in and rememberMe fields?

Answer (score 3):

If you copy original content or scrape non-negligible amounts of data from the ft website, you will rightly be blocked as you will be violating their T&Cs (not to mention copyright law).

The FT is partly funded by advertisements.  If you bypass these by using Python you are eroding a legimitimate revenue source.

I use this script to pull my watchlists into Excel, which I used to do using copy/paste.  I do not use it for analytics or to read articles.  I read the FT via the browser generating a fair degree of advert-viewing traffic daily.

Please do not abuse this.  If you do, it is likely to result in every paying subscriber being blocked from doing even tiny amounts of navigating in Python.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)

url='https://accounts.ft.com/login?location=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ft.com%2F'

browser.open(url)
form=browser.get_form()
form['email']=""
form['password']=""
browser.session.headers['Referer'] = url
browser.submit_form(form)
```

There is an FT Developer Programme if you wish to perform Datamining and so on:
https://developer.ft.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have zero intention of violating copyright law or even sharing this script at all. My intention is to simply download the daily newspaper as PDF (which FT offer as a button) and email myself when it's ready. I'll give this a shot and see if it works.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  Please can you uprate me and resolve the question?  My priveleges are rubbish on stackoverflow at the moment...